# NSURL not being passed between view controllers

Tags: ios

I am creating an `NSURL` in one view controller and then using it in another. The URL contains the correct string in the view controller where it is being created but in the view controller I am passing it to, it is `NULL`.

```
NSData *data = feed.imageData;

NSData *stringData = feed.urlString;
self.stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.stringForURL = [self.stringForURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.stringForURL];
```

And here is where I pass it to the other view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Code to create detailed view and set properties
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        detailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        detailViewController.managedObject = object;
        NSLog(@"Here is the final URL:%@", [self.finalURL absoluteString]);
        detailViewController.finalURL = self.finalURL;


        DetailViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];

}
```

In secondviewcontroller.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *finalURL;
```

In secondviewcontroller.m:

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:self.finalURL options:nil];
```

Comment: how do you declare finalURL property in your DetailViewController?

Comment: Here I updated my question @Chancy

Comment: @matthew : Are you sure, you are setting to the original detailviewController? or to a new instance of DetailViewController?

Comment: And it does log correctly?

Comment: finalURL have you synthesized this property?

Comment: In the first view controller, the url prints but in the second, it prints NULL @JoePasq

Comment: Whats your viewController hierarchy? how you navigate to second viewController?

Comment: @BilalSaifudeen I have assigned assigned another variable the way I did there before in the view controller, could this cause the problem, and if it does, should I declare it in my .h and use the same one throughout?

Comment: So I pass it to the other view controller in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in a UITableView. @BilalSaifudeen

Comment: @matthew Post that code to get better understanding

Comment: There, Added code above @BilalSaifudeen

Comment: remove the second DetailViewController you alloc

Comment: Removing the line works, but when I take another video and create another cell where the corresponding URL should be, the urls for both cells are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing it correct, but you created one more instance of detailViewController and pushes that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Code to create detailed view and set properties
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    detailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    detailViewController.managedObject = object;
    NSLog(@"Here is the final URL:%@", [self.finalURL absoluteString]);
    detailViewController.finalURL = self.finalURL;


    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: yes thank you, It was right in front of me, I was just not looking at those two lines at the bottom. Thank you so much!

Comment: one more question, This works for the first video recorded, but if I take another video and have two cells, the url's are not working again.

Comment: @matthew Track and analyse your code step by step and log necessary values  to see that works as expected.

Comment: So it looks like it is saving both URL's to core data but then when it is being retrieved, it's not picking between the two URL's saved and returning nothing. Is there some way to use the second URL saved with the second cell and third with third and so on?